# How to make span go to the next line

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Im using `tailwind css` by the way. How can i auto `<br>` this text where it just goes to the next line after certain `width`

```html
<div class="w-0 flex-1 flex items-center overflow-y-auto max-w-full">
  <label class="font-thin font-semibold text-yellow-300">||</label>

  <span class="ml-2 flex-1">Large  text that would normally need &lt;br&gt;</span>
</div>
```

full thing

```html
<div class="flex flex-col bg-white px-8 py-6 max-w-sm mx-auto rounded-lg shadow-md overflow-y-auto">
                  <ul class="border border-gray-200 rounded-md divide-y divide-gray-200">
                    <li class="pl-3 pr-4 py-3 text-sm">
                      <div class="block flex-1 flex items-center overflow-y-auto max-w-full">
                        <label class="font-thin font-semibold text-yellow-300">||</label>
  
                        <span class="ml-2 flex-1 block overflow-y overflow-x-hidden" style="display: block;">
                          resume_back_end_developer.pdfskmaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      
                    </li>
                    
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                    
                </div>
```

Comment: add for css: `span { display: block; }` which will transform the span into a block level element and by default be dispalyed in a next line.

Comment: You added a second snippet with an impossible word !? It does not **clarify your question** at all . where do you want a line break to happen ? *(use any unknown language if you wish, but with words that have a length that reflects reality).* also add the CSS that goes along your class, so it is not out of context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is `break-words`. It will add line breaks after a certain length, even breaking words if needed.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="flex flex-col bg-white px-8 py-6 max-w-sm mx-auto rounded-lg shadow-md overflow-y-auto">
  <ul class="border border-gray-200 rounded-md divide-y divide-gray-200">
    <li class="pl-3 pr-4 py-3 text-sm">
      <div class="flex-1 flex items-center overflow-y-auto max-w-full">
        <label class="font-semibold text-yellow-300">||</label>
        <span class="ml-2 flex-1 block overflow-y overflow-x-hidden break-words"> resume_back_end_developer.pdfskmaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa </span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To not mess up other `<span>` elements, add a custom class to that specific span. In my sample I added the class `br`: `<span class="ml-2 flex-1 br">`

Next I add this for the css: `.br { display: block; }`. That will change the `span` with the class `br`to change from inline-element to a block level element. As such a linebreak behavior will happen by default.

```css
.br {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="w-0 flex-1 flex items-center overflow-y-auto max-w-full">
  <label class="font-thin font-semibold text-yellow-300">||</label>

  <span class="ml-2 flex-1 br">Large  text that would normally need &lt;br&gt;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: didnt work it just puts a scroll horizontally

Comment: in the snippet it clearly works. Where is the scrollbar coming from? are any other css you use interferring with it?

Comment: Please see what I have added